# displaying relevant date formats in months days minutes or seconds?

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to convert a mysql timestamp to time in months or days or hours or minutes.

so the output will look like this:

added 1 month ago  /  added: 0 hours ago   /  added: 21 minutes ago  / added 30 seconds ago

so i only want one format of time depending on how many minutes or how many hours or how many days etc, so 60 minutes converts to 1 hour ago or 24 hours converts to 1 day ago and 48 hours converts to 2 dayS ago.

so far i have this code:

```
<?
    $datetime1 = new DateTime();
    $datetime2 = new DateTime ($news['date_added']);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    str_replace('0 hours', '', $variable);
    echo $interval->format('%h hours %i minutes');
    ?>
```

and this outputs the following:

added 0 hours ago 57 minutes ago.

can someone help me or show me what id need to do in order to get the formats to display right, im really new to php and am not sure how i can do this. thank you.

Comment: Please confirm if I got this right: if `$interval` is > 30 days, report as `N months ago`. If it's > 24 hours, report `N days ago`. If it's > 1 hour, report `N hours ago`. If it's > 1 minute, report `N minutes ago`; otherwise, report `N seconds ago`. That suggests a certain logical flow for the code, doesn't it...

Comment: If you would like to make life easier and let javascript do the job for you, here is a good plugin to use: http://timeago.yarp.com

Comment: @floris yes that sounds right

Comment: OK - in that case, see my solution.

Answer (score 3):

From http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

Just change $precision to 1 when you call the function and add in whatever text you want to come before and after the date.  You'll have to make sure you convert your date objects to timestamps, but that shouldn't be a problem for you.

```
/**
 * this code assumes php >= 5.1.0. if using < 5.1, read
 * php.net/strtotime and change the condition for checking
 * for failure from strtotime()
 */

// $t1, $t2: unix times, or strtotime parseable
// $precision: max number of units to output
// $abbr: if true, use "hr" instead of "hour", etc.
function date_diff ($t1, $t2, $precision = 6, $abbr = false) {
    if (preg_match('/\D/', $t1) && ($t1 = strtotime($t1)) === false)
        return false;

    if (preg_match('/\D/', $t2) && ($t2 = strtotime($t2)) === false)
        return false;

    if ($t1 > $t2)
        list($t1, $t2) = array($t2, $t1);

    $diffs = array(
        'year' => 0, 'month' => 0, 'day' => 0,
        'hour' => 0, 'minute' => 0, 'second' => 0,
    );

    $abbrs = array(
        'year' => 'yr', 'month' => 'mth', 'day' => 'day',
        'hour' => 'hr', 'minute' => 'min', 'second' => 'sec'
    );

    foreach (array_keys($diffs) as $interval) {
        while ($t2 >= ($t3 = strtotime("+1 ${interval}", $t1))) {
            $t1 = $t3;
            ++$diffs[$interval];
        }
    }

    $stack = array();
    foreach ($diffs as $interval => $num)
        $stack[] = array($num, ($abbr ? $abbrs[$interval] : $interval) . ($num != 1 ? 's' : ''));

    $ret = array();
    while (count($ret) < $precision && ($item = array_shift($stack)) !== null) {
        if ($item[0] > 0)
            $ret[] = "{$item[0]} {$item[1]}";
    }

    return implode(', ', $ret);
}

$t1 = 'Feb 4, 2008 12:16:00';
$t2 = 'Jul 3, 2006 16:15:30';

echo date_diff($t1, $t2), "\n",
    date_diff($t1, $t2, 3), "\n",
    date_diff($t1, $t2, 2, true), "\n";

?>
```

Comment: Wow - this is good. A bit more than was asked for maybe, but worth an upvote for the flexibility. Did you have this handy, or did you just write it now?

Comment: I cited the source at the top of the post. :)  Thanks.

Comment: OK - I had not followed the link down to the examples. Less impressed by your speedcoding, more impressed by your ability to find exactly the right piece of code quickly! The upvote stands...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution. You format the time difference as a string with months-days-hours-minutes-seconds, then look through that string for the first non-zero number: that's the one you want...

```
$mdhms = explode('-',$interval->format('%m-%d-%H-%i-%s'));

$labels = Array(' months', ' days', ' hours', ' minutes', ' seconds');
$i = 0;
foreach($mdhms as $t){
  if($t > 0) break;
  $i+=1;
}
if ($i < 5) echo "It happened ".$t.$labels[$i]." ago";
else echo "It is happening right now!"
```

Comment: Sorry - sloppy transcription from computer with php to computer with browser (don't ask); lost the `explode` statement which turns the formatted date into an array representing months, days, ... It is back now.